# How do I remove an entry in RealtimeDatabase within onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, firebase

When I click a button, I want to delete an entry in a ReyclerView that is in a constraint layout on Firebase Realtime Database. Unfortunately I can't do that. How do I get the Chil ID to remove the respective entry?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlacesAdapter.MyAdapter holder, 
@SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

  holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     placesL.remove(position);
     PlacesAdapter.this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
     notifyItemRangeChanged(position, placesL.size());
    }
 });
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: Since you're saying that you're using the Realtime Database, please note that you can use the same logic, simply propagate the ID of the item you want to be deleted to the View and perform the delete operation accordingly.